# Notification doesn't autoCancel in 5.0

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to Cancel Notification on Tap of Notification which is working perfectly fine below 5.0. But somehow that same notification is not `autoCancel` in Android 5.0

Here's what i used to `cancelNotification` *(Works smoothly < 5.0)*

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx,
uniqueID, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_mobcast_notification)
                .setContentTitle(message)
                .setContentText(title)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, title,
                resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(-1);
        mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle(
                mBuilder).bigPicture(
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath, options)).build();

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(434, notification);
```

Tried :-

*Try to cancel the notification where the `pendingIntent` leads to. But no still notification is there on Notification Bar(5.0)*

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
```

*What could be the `Extra Flag` which i missed out to set for 5.0 will `autoCancel` notification on Tap of it?*

Comment: Have you found anything? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I used following code, it works perfect, you can try:

```
public void showNotification(View view) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Message")
                .setContentText("New Message")
                .setTicker("Alert New Message")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Intent moreInfoIntent = new Intent(this, MoreInfoNotification.class);

        TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MoreInfoNotification.class);

        taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(moreInfoIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(notifId, notificationBuilder.build());
        isNotificActive = true;

    }
```

Comment: It's apparently not working with 5.0. Notification doesn't cancel on tap of it.

Comment: Could you please provide the whole working sample?. Cause these autoCancel is pulling my hair in 5.0